# Blazor WASM Core Hosted and MudBlazor CSS Inline issue

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am trying to add MudBlazor to my Blazor WASM Core Hosted application (.net 7).  I followed the directions on the MudBlazor site but when I run my app, the console fills up with these types of errors and my styles don't get displayed correctly:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-ktKK7Zv7htgNiUfk5gyriqVJUMU7emNct5K2m6GIbXs='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

My MainLayout.razor page looks like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<div>
    <MudLayout>
        <NavMenu></NavMenu>
        <MudAppBar>
            My Application
        </MudAppBar>
        <MudDrawer Open="true">

        </MudDrawer>
        <MudMainContent>
            @Body
        </MudMainContent>
    </MudLayout>
</div>
```

My NavMenu.razor looks like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<div>
    <MudNavMenu>
        <MudNavLink Href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/servers" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">Servers</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavGroup Title="Settings" Expanded="true">
            <MudNavLink Href="/users" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">Users</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/security" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">Security</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>
        <MudNavLink Href="/about" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">About</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavMenu>
</div>
```

my _Host.cshtml looks like this:

```
//head
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/myApp.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="MyApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

//footer
<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" ></script>
```

In My Client Program.cs I added:

```
services.AddMudServices();
services.AddScoped<IDialogService, DialogService>();
```

How can I resolve these issues to the controls are rendered correctly (without jeopardizing security)?

Thanks!

Comment: in `_host.cshtml` the blazor.webassembly script needs to be added before the mudblazor script.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried swapping the order of the two js files but that did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Seems there's an issue for this, https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/4529, try updating to the latest version.